# PHP MVC Framework : Yii vs DooPHP

Tags: php, yii, doophp

I've only experienced with CodeIgniter 1.7 roughly two years ago, quite okay but there were flaws such as you can have only one controller, no redirection to another controller, etc; I was also playing around with CakePHP a little bit but to be frank I was not very used to its "Ruby on Rails" approach of convention over configuration, so in the end I just gave up.

I am planning to have a new casual web application after work for myself, and this time I'd like to try something new, I've done a little research and found two candidates:

[Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) and [DooPHP](http://www.doophp.com/)

Both sound very promising but I'd also like to hear the advise from their users, hopefully this would get a decent feature comparison like [the thread about CakePHP vs CodeIgniter on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548923/cakephp-vs-codeigniter)

Comment: Have you given CI another try since?

Comment: @Piers: unfortunately no, not ever since. But I will start the check now, hopefully I can see something more interesting :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, from what I've seen from the people I follow on Twitter, there is a little bit of dissent amongst CI developers.

http://dhorrigan.com/blog/article/the-future-of-me-and-codeigniter as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the debate is between Yii and DooPHP, go for Yii. Not only is DooPHP a horrible name (seriously, would you ever want to tell a business client "I used DooPHP"?), but Yii is simply solid. Thus far, the versioning has been fair. When I used Rails, I was bombarded by crazy changes every month or two and "forced" to upgrade constantly. Yii has added real value features each version, without all the hype that forces a ton of upgrading all the time. The community is solid, the performance is great, and despite a decent learning curve it's not difficult to get up and running quickly.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you say you use Yii? some of my colleagues still think I made that name up.

Comment: I do say it, and when people are puzzled I explain it's like Wii, but Yii. At any rate, it's a whole lot better than something that sounds like it's done in the bathroom. :)

Answer (score 3):

I tried CI, CakePHP(early stages) and ZEND. But now im using DooPHP, becouse its just simple as hell framework, very, very fast and I dont need to wory about all boring stuff like error handling and so on. I just write code. On doophp it depends on you, will you have 1 controller or many - it doesnt make any diffrence, becuse of routing - and it have very powerful routing engine with regexp, header redirects with codes and so on. There is no need any tutorials for it, becouse it have simple documentation what is enough.

If you need simple framework, where you can just write code, and forget about all boring stuff, DooPHP is the best framework you can have.